# SQL Access Adding a colum with a default value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a query that is part of a fiction table. The problem is this

> Add to the `FICTION` table a new character column named `BEST_SELLER`
>   that is one character in length. Then set the default value for all
>   columns to N.

This is how I set it up.

```
Alter Table Fiction Add Column Best_Seller Char(1) Default “N” ;
```

Is there anything I seem to be doing wrong because in access I get the error in Alter Table Statement.

Comment: What is your RDBMS and what is the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with double quotation, try to use single quote

```
Alter Table Fiction Add Column Best_Seller Char(1) SET Default 'N' ;
```

Comment: Thank for trying to solve the question.  Still getting the same issue when I change it to single quotes.

Comment: @JacobUnterberger I've added `set` try it now please